# WPF ItemsSource internal collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have a UserControl with an ObservableCollection property. This property is supposed to be used for binding, however I don't want it to be visible outside of the assembly in order to satisfy the basic rules of OOP. Here is a demonstrating example which works, but when I change the access modifier of *Data* to *internal* it doesn't work anymore:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Root">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=Root}"/>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Data.Add("XXX");
            Data.Add("YYY");
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Data.Add("ZZZ " + i)));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: A better pattern would be to use MVVM and leave the object as public on a ViewModel. I don't see how exposing a public get breaks encapsulation for your example. Maybe you should ask yourself "why" you want to make the property internal. In my experience, locking down objects with access modifiers without good reason usually causes headaches and hard to maintain code in the future. (for example, when wanting to write unit tests)

Comment: I agree. However in my specific case the design and the behaviour of my UserControl is very dependent on some of these public properties (which are also used for binding) so it could cause a weird behaviour or even an Exception if they were modified by a programmer using my UserControl library.

Comment: If that is the case than perhaps you should not use binding and modify the collection from the codebehind. Adding a Name to the ListBox will allow you to manipulate the data from the codebehind without exposing the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set ItemSource in MainWindow constructor

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Root">
    <ListBox Name="listbox"/>
</Window>
```

And Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        internal ObservableCollection<string> Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listbox.ItemSource = this.Data;
            Data.Add("XXX");
            Data.Add("YYY");
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Data.Add("ZZZ " + i)));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ye, it really works :] Well I will still have a problem with this for some other (non-collection) properties, but this definitely answers my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding in WPF works only with public properties.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes)

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation